# How does Vagrant accomplish such small box file sizes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I've created a Vagrant base image file for Ubuntu Linux Precise Pangolin 32-bit
with the following command:

```
vagrant box add precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
```

This `precise32.box` file is then placed under `C:\Users\MyUserNameHere\.vagrant.d\boxes\precise32`
whose contents include a subdirectory called virtualbox containing among other things a file
called `box.ovf` measuring 14KB and a file called `box-disk1.vmdk` measuring only 288.318KB.

On the other hand I've also installed an Ubuntu Linux Precise Pangolin 32-bit system within
Oracle VirtualBox using 12GB of dynamically allocated storage and exported the disk image
to an `.ova` file. This `.ova` file measures 1.63GB.

I am having a hard time figuring out why one file is in the order of a few KB whereas the `.ova` is over six times as large. Anyone have any ideas? Why am I seeing such a big difference between the file sizes of the exported `.ova` file and the `.vmdk` file managed by Vagrant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the reason, I finally figured it out.

The files under `C:\Users\MyUserNameHere.vagrant.d\boxes\precise32`
are just base files upon which actual systems are built. The real
instance of the precise32 box is then placed under a directory
such as:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\VirtualBox VMs\name_of_the_directory_containing_the_Vagrantfile_default_1384903788
```

Which is created once the `vagrant up` command is issued from such directory
containing the Vagrantfile. In my case the `.vmdk` file placed here is 1.03GB
which makes more sense.